# Autoplay Policy Changes: how to allow sound with user gesture

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, autoplay, mute

I know that as of 2019 the browsers block autoplay sound, and as such, my video bg code only works if I add a mute - which I did.

It is my understanding that if the user interacts with the page, the sound is allowed?

So my question is... how do I add a command or javascript or jquery of some sort, to allow sound when the user interacts. Like to reverse the mute, if they click an element I target on the page.

I'll put my demo site in the comments.

Comment: Hi. whats up? sorry for delayed response. my gmail is full of github notifications, so i didn't saw your email. glad that the other question is answered. for this one, you can use normal video tag for background, and unmute it with click.here is the sample: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/vYBQEgz and here is the js code: `window.onclick = function (){
  document.querySelector('.video-background video').muted = false;
}`

Comment: Hello my friend! :p Mine is an iframe. I changed video to iframe in your js code but it doesn't work. Can you refresh my page?

Comment: Can we do it with my current setup of youtube iframe tag and external css file?

Comment: hi. no, you can't unmute video in iframe. details: iframe is separate document and if you want to unmute anything on iframe, user should interacted with iframe (click the background video in iframe, not a button outside iframe). also if you want to call youtube unMute function, you should use Script tag, not normal iframe. but the problem is that this way doesn't allow you to have 
a fullscreen video and without controlls. so in general, there is no way. so just change it to normal video tag.

Comment: Is it possible to put the youtube link in a video tag though? Or I have to download it and make it an mp4? I'll be online in 30 min

Comment: you can't put the link directly. you should download it. since its long, you should cut it as well. there is some online tools to download/cut(trim) the video, just search "online youtube trim".

Comment: Oh... dang. Yeah, I know how to do it. But I have tons of pages with these videos. I guess I have to download and cut them all. :p Ok I'll work on it over the weekend and let you know if I get stuck with making the code work.

Comment: yep i think it's the only way. good luck :)

Comment: Ok I'm gonna start practicing this now. :p Can I do it with the existent stylesheet, change iframe to video, but use video tag with clipped video downloaded as mp4? Basically using my original stylesheet.

Comment: Hi. i think no, probably you should change some styles to make it full screen and centered.

Comment: hi. glad it worked. for full screen, apply this styles to it: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/wvwZapb (just css section)

Comment: also for your mail, for first question: i can't see the question on stack , because its closed and it gives me 404 not found.

Comment: for second question, didn't get it entirely. you have a page, and you have an i frame in it. do you want to stop the cookies , or clear the cookies, or clear the cache of iframe? (they are 3 different things, and some of them may not be possible.)

Comment: Hi. This works perfectly now, except for a small distortion. Let's just chat on email so the comments here stay relative to the q. :)